# Free object memory

Tags: javascript, html, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have a global object 'm1' on my html5 web page.
Here is how it's defined:

```
m1:
    {
        def: null
    },
```

I'm working with that object throught the game by adding more variables to it (actually it's graphic sprites):

```
m1.actor1 = new CreateSprite(...);
```

At some point of time I don't need m1 object anymore and ALL of the resources taken by its inner variables. Would that action tell garbage collector to totally erase it? :

```
m1 = { };
```

Does it mean that after this object recreation I get m1.actor1 erased as well?

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with javascript and HTML5 ?

Comment: You should just search there are lots of posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437125/how-do-i-explicitly-release-a-javascript-object-from-within-the-object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523172/freeing-javascript-object  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript

Comment: Objects are eligible for garbage collection when there are no remaining references to them. So yes, if you assign m1 to some *other* object then the original object can be garbage collected. Any secondary objects referenced by properties of the original main object can also be garbage collected - assuming no other variables refer to them either. (Note that this doesn't make the garbage collector run immediately, it just means that when it does it will collect those objects.)